# What is the purpose of the checks like 'VARCHAR2' = 'NUMBER' in auto-generated sqldeveloper scripts?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've realized that sqldeveloper program is using some checks that I've never seen before when creating auto-generated SQL scripts, and it makes no sense to me. Anyone knows the purpose of them? for example the 'VARCHAR2' = 'NUMBER' comparison.

```
begin
  if 'VARCHAR2' = 'NUMBER' and length('VARCHAR2')>0 and length('100')>0 then
    execute immediate 'alter table "MYTABLE" add(COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(, 100))';
  elsif ('VARCHAR2' = 'NUMBER' and length('VARCHAR2')>0 and length('100')=0) or
    'VARCHAR2' = 'VARCHAR2' then
    execute immediate 'alter table "MYTABLE" add(COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(100))';
  else
    execute immediate 'alter table "MYTABLE" add(COLUMN1 VARCHAR2)';
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: It feels that SQL comes from a template with placeholders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is probably written more like this:

```
begin
  if '&type' = 'NUMBER'
     and length('&type')>0
     and length('&size')>0
  then
    execute immediate 'alter table "&tablename" add(&columnname &type(&scale, &size))';
  elsif (   '&type' = 'NUMBER'
         and length('&type')>0
         and length('&size')=0
        )
        or '&type' = 'VARCHAR2'
  then
    execute immediate 'alter table "&tablename" add(&columnname &type(&size))';
  else
    execute immediate 'alter table "&tablename" add(&columnname &type)';
  end if;
end;
/
```

You are seeing the output when the substitution variables have been applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the system uses dynamically generated code that comes from a fixed format that contains some kind of placeholders or, more likely, variable concatenations:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "' || TABLENAME || " ADD ...';
```

A column type can have three formats:

- `TYPENAME`
- `TYPENAME(param1)`
- `TYPENAME(param1, param2)`

... and they have a template that covers all three situations by doing carefully calculated comparisons.